# Android device how to run one program?

Tags: android

Here is the question I have android device version 4.1.1 and ı want change the android working style. For example I restart my android device and want to see my application on screen just one. Another app for example camera or notepad ı dont want to see that just one program in my android device and I use that . How can ı programming that ?

ı will try again ı wanna root my android device for my claims how can ı do that

Comment: Sounds offtopic, can you try to rephrase the question? Not easy to understand what you mean.

Comment: you are right but ı cant explain that

Comment: ı will try again ı wanna root my android device for my claims how can ı do that

Comment: If you just want to root your device do a Google search? .. something like Cyanogenmod might be what you are looking for

Comment: but my device is not aviable in anywhere ı have to do this myself how can ı simple why ?

Comment: buy another device, I guess.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: special device its a tablet but very different tablet

Comment: ı cant buy another device ı have to write app for device and device show only this app not another app for example calculator or settings